# How to make a nginx reverse proxy direct to tor hidden service?

Tags: nginx, service, proxy, hidden, tor

Is it possible to have a clearnet website tunnel through a tor hidden service?
Example if someone owned blah.com and it pointed to server IP 1.2.3.4, but wanted 1.2.3.4 to make proxy requests to a hidden service.

The point would be to have a clearnet "looking" website while having the contents of the website itself on a hidden server, basically what proxy_pass would do except it needs to be connecting to localhost.

Any ideas how this would/could be done?

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this yourself?  Normally questions this broad will get taken down, however your question seems like a good exception to the rule. +1

Comment: One thing I had attempted was using tor2web, by having blah.com proxy_pass to tor2web proxy, but this brought problems with certificates and also is a security issue using tor2web itself.

I think nginx would have to be modified to allow proxy_pass to go through a proxy first for this to work

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I'm a bit late to the party. I wanted to do the exact same thing a few days ago and couldn't find a workable solution to the problem. Hence, after days of research and some development, I came up with `tor-nginx-proxy` - a docker image which helps us achieve this.

Read more about it - https://harshitbudhraja.com/port-a-website-to-the-dark-web-in-under-2-minutes

Answer (score 0):

yes. it's possible.
proxy_pass nginx to socat that proxy to tor

```
/usr/bin/socat tcp4-LISTEN:$PORT,reuseaddr,fork,keepalive,bind=$IP SOCKS4A:127.0.0.1:$URL_ONION:$PORT_ONION,socksport=9050
```

replace $PORT , $IP, $URL_ONION and $PORT_ONION with your data

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't having too much luck with socat/privoxy so [I wrote this simple docker image](https://git.fenomen.ro/erik/simple-tor-proxy).
Instructions are in the readme file.

Comment: It isn't recommended to reply with answers pointing to links containing the solution.